# Debian network bridge configuration - /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, debian, bridge, configuration, syntax

I'm running a Lenny Xen dom0 hosting multiple virtual machines in a routed IP setup. To get an additional private subnet, I created the bridge xenbr0 in the dom0 with the following commands:

```
brctl addbr xenbr0
ifconfig xenbr0 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig xenbr0 up
```

This works as expected, and domU interfaces are added to the bridge by Xen on VM start. My only problem is: how the heck do i specify this configuration in /etc/network/interfaces that it remains permanent and the bridge is available after a reboot? I tried the following config as found on a lot of tutorials:

```
auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 10.0.0.0
  broadcast 10.0.0.255
  bridge_stp no
```

I get 2 different errors, depending on if the bridge already exists or not. If it doesn't exist:

```
root@dom0:~# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
root@dom0:~# /etc/init.d/networking restart
Reconfiguring network interfaces...if-up.d/mountnfs[eth0]: waiting for interface xenbr0 before doing NFS mounts (warning).
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
xenbr0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFNETMASK: No such device
SIOCSIFBRDADDR: No such device
xenbr0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
xenbr0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
Failed to bring up xenbr0.
done.
```

And if it exists:

```
root@dom0:~# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
xenbr0          8000.000000000000       no
root@dom0:~# /etc/init.d/networking restart
Reconfiguring network interfaces...if-up.d/mountnfs[eth0]: waiting for interface xenbr0 before doing NFS mounts (warning).
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up xenbr0.
done.
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction please? The bridge works fine when created manually, i just need the right config file entries. The most tutorials I found add some devices to the bridge in the config, is that maybe the problem why it is not working? I don't have any interfaces I want to add to the bridge on creation as they get added later on VM start...

Thanks,
Mathias

Comment: Have you checked the Xen mailing list and http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenNetworking ?

Comment: Sure, the setup works as desired. I just need to know how to setup the bridge in /etc/network/interfaces to have it available on a dom0 reboot without having to manually create the bridge over the shell. So it's not a Xen specific problem, but debian-related (I just need to know the right config file syntax).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to miss the most important line:

```
auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet static
  bridge_ports eth0 eth4 eth7    # bridge traffic between these interfaces
  bridge_stp no
  address 10.0.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 10.0.0.0
  broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

`man` says:
  If you need to specify the interfaces more flexibly, you can use
  the following syntax (most useful on a Xen dom0):

```
     bridge_ports regex (eth|vif).*
```

This means to evaluate (as in  egrep(1))  the  expressions  that
  follow  after  "regex".

Comment: I don't have any ports to bridge when the bridge is created as the only bridged interfaces belong to the VMs which get created later. However, i re-checked my config and noticed that I had 2 "up route add..." entries standing below the bridge config which belonged to the eth0 interface. I also added "bridge_ports none" to the bridge config and now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

How about a script that runs after startup to perform the commands you want?

Comment: Sure, that would be possible, but using debian's built in network scripts would be the cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove the `network-manager` package. It often interferes with manual interface settings.